# Next / Link doesn't route to the next page when clicked before the page has completely loaded

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, next-link

```
import Link from 'next/link';

...

<Link href="/test">test</Link>
```

Clicking on the link doesn't route to the next page when the network is slow, and the entire page hasn't been completely loaded (all the js chunks haven't been fetched from the network, takes about 5secs on slow 3G).

But, when I wait for the entire page and all js files to load fully (about 10seconds), it starts working fine.

Comment: It sounds as Next/react prevent Link route while page not completed loaded.

Comment: @CarlosSpohr
any way around it?

Comment: @AbhishekKumar Are you certain that's the case? I'm not able to reproduce it. If you completely disable JavaScript in devtools, does the `Link` not work?

Comment: hey

you can check this link.

https://www.loom.com/share/42eeaef615e549ffae6b4f35875f1fd5

@juliomalves

Comment: importing link dynamically, and using prefetch={false} seems to resolve this.
i've no idea why though

/////////n

const Link = dynamic(() => import('next/link'), {
  ssr: false,
});

<Link href={`/${slug}`} passHref prefetch={false}>
sad
</Link>